# Internal Server Error with SQL Code

Tags: php, html, mysql, internal-server-error

I am trying to insert values into a mysql database and I am getting an "Internal Server Error" and do not know why.  I am using an upload form to get user data and then using an upload processor file to write the data to the server.  The form is based off of a working tutorial online so everything works, but whenever I added the SQL code, it stopped working.  My code is below, and I appreciate your time looking at it.

```
<?php 

// Upload form based off of http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766

// make a note of the current working directory, relative to root. 
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 

// make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded file 
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/'; 

// make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it 
$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.form.php'; 

// make a note of the location of the success page 
$uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.success.php'; 

// fieldname used within the file <input> of the HTML form 
$fieldname = 'file'; 

$promoName = 'sale_name';
$expirDate = 'sale_expir';

// Now let's deal with the upload 

// possible PHP upload errors 
$errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                4 => 'no file was attached'); 

// check the upload form was actually submitted else print the form 
isset($_POST['submit']) 
    or error('the upload form is needed', $uploadForm); 

// check for PHP's built-in uploading errors 
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0) 
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm); 

// check that the file we are working on really was the subject of an HTTP upload 
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name']) 
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm); 

// validation... since this is an image upload script we should run a check   
// to make sure the uploaded file is in fact an image. Here is a simple check: 
// getimagesize() returns false if the file tested is not an image. 
@getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name']) 
    or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm); 

// make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is not already 
// taken... if it is already taken keep trying until we find a vacant one 
// sample filename: 1140732936-filename.jpg 
$now = time(); 
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'])) 
{ 
    $now++; 
} 

// now let's move the file to its final location and allocate the new filename to it 
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename) 
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm); 

// these commands move the information onto the database
$imageURL = $uploadsDirectory.$uploadFilename;

$host = '***removed***';
$dbName = '***removed***';
$dbUser = '***removed***';
$dbPass = '***removed***';

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $dbUser, $dbPass);

if (!$conn){
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'Connected successfully!';
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO '$dbName'.sales (name, date, saleImage) VALUES ('$promoName', '$expirDate', '$imageURL');";

mysql_select_db($dbName, $conn);

mysql_query($sql, $conn);

mysql_close($conn);
// database work is done

// If you got this far, everything has worked and the file has been successfully saved. 
// We are now going to redirect the client to a success page. 
header('Location: ' . $uploadSuccess); 

// The following function is an error handler which is used 
// to output an HTML error page if the file upload fails 
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5) 
{ 
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL="$location""); 
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."n". 
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."nn". 
    '<html lang="en">'."n". 
    '    <head>'."n". 
    '        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">'."nn". 
    '        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">'."nn". 
    '    <title>Upload error</title>'."nn". 
    '    </head>'."nn". 
    '    <body>'."nn". 
    '    <div id="Upload">'."nn". 
    '        <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."nn". 
    '        <p>An error has occurred: '."nn". 
    '        <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."nn". 
    '         The upload form is reloading</p>'."nn". 
    '     </div>'."nn". 
    '</html>'; 
    exit; 
} // end error handler 

?>
```

Comment: Internal Server Error ?? Have you checked your .htaccess file first ?

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess file is fine.  Is there anything in specific that I should check for in it?

Comment: I have answered your question. Check it out. Make sure you use your .htaccess properly. Or if you're not sure about .htaccess. Delete it and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this code in your 95th line:

```
header("Refresh: $seconds; URL="$location"");
```

Which should be

```
header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
```